# Is Firefox's Password Manager account-dependant, or device-dependant?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

If I log out from my Firefox account, will my sister have access to the Password Manager if she fires up the browser?

And also, if I use a friend's computer, fire up his Firefox and log into my account, can I use the Password Manager from there?

Sorry for this very basic questions, I'm the kind of person who forgets about the basics very often, lol.

Comment: Would you be just closing the browser and your sister would continue to use the same Windows session, or would you log-off Windows and your sister would login as her own Windows user?  When you start Firefox, do you each have a separate user profile that you select (or if you login Windows as different users, is Firefox set to use a different profile for each of you)?  I assumed Windows; is that the OS you're using (and what version)?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the Firefox password manager is account-dependant, but you can also [secure your password manager with a master password](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import#w_protecting-your-passwords). With a setting in Firefox, passwords are stored in the cookies, and you will have to disable that on a public or insecure computer.

Answer (score -1):

BTW, this is not a basic question. It relates to security.

So first, if it is under Windows check first your accounts and see from there have you limited access to Firefox.

The password manager must have a setting to set up the trusted browsers, or to check from which devices you have logged yourself in.

If you see suspicious activity it might be your sister.

The other option is the master password for the extension/add-on/plugin.